# Angular 2 Dependency Injection singletons

Tags: angular

I have a standalone class called `Poller`. I want to inject shared *configured* instances of this class into different components. For example if I try the following:

```
export const QuickPollingService = new OpaqueToken('quickPoller');
export let quickPollingServiceProvider = provide(QuickPollingService, {
    useFactory: () => {
        return new Poller(200);
    },
});
export const SlowPollingService = new OpaqueToken('slowPoller');
export let slowPollingServiceProvider = provide(SlowPollingService, {
    useFactory: () => {
        return new Poller(1000);
    },
});
```

Injecting like below (with a correct import path) gives me a name not found error:

```
export class ImageComponent {
    constructor(
        private element: ElementRef,
        private poller: QuickPollingService
    ) {}
}
```

What is the right way to inject a configured class instance in Angular 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `@Inject` decorator in your case to inject your dependency!

```
export class ImageComponent {
  constructor(
    private element: ElementRef,
    @Inject(QuickPollingService) private poller: Poller
  ) {}
}
```

In your case `QuickPollingService` corresponds to an opaque token and isn't the type (a class) that you want to inject. You want to inject a type of `Poller` that is created using the provider registered with the opaque token `QuickPollingService`.

In fact, the following is enough:

```
export let quickPollingServiceProvider = provide(Poller, {
  useFactory: () => {
    return new Poller(200);
  }
});
```

In this case you can use the following:

```
export class ImageComponent {
  constructor(
    private element: ElementRef,
    private poller: Poller
  ) {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. I've expanded the code example in the question to clarify what I was aiming for.

Answer (score 2):

**Use `@Inject()` for `OpaqueToken`**

If you use

```
provide(SomeOpaqueToken ...
```

then you need to inject like

```
export class ImageComponent {
    constructor(
        private element: ElementRef,
        // v added decorator
        @Inject(SomeOpaqueToken) private poller: QuickPollingService
    ) {}
}
```

**Use type instead of `OpaqueToken`**

otherwise register the provider like

```
export let quickPollingServiceProvider = provide(Poller, {
    useFactory: () => {
        return new Poller(200);
    },
});
```

(don't use `OpaqueToken` in this case)

Also ensure you add the provider somewhere like

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [quickPollingServiceProvider]);
```

**Typical use case for `OpaqueToken`**

`OpaqueToken` can be used when you can't or don't want to use a specific type for registering and requesting a dependency.

Instead of an `OpaqueToken` you also can just use a string.

If you want to inject a primitive value where the type is not distinctive enough you have to use `OpaqueToken` or a string. For example when you want to inject some configuration value.

```
@Injectable()
class Poller {
  constructor(@Inject('pollingInterval' private interval:number) {}
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    provide('pollingInterval': {useValue: 200}),
    Poller]);
```

This way your provider would be simplified and you don't need to use a factory because the `interval` dependency of `Poller` is provided by Angulars DI.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.  I've expanded the code example in the question to clarify what I was aiming for. There seems to be multiple ways to achieve this.

Comment: In your example (updated code) using `OpaqueToken` is a good fit. There is no way to distinguish between the slow and quick instances by type. An alternative would be to create different classes like `class PollerBase`, `class SlowPoller extends PollerBase` and `class QuickPoller extends PollerBase` then you could provide them by type but I wouldn't this consider an improvement over your current code if you do this only for DI.